# write file with define constant having error to not put his value

Tags: php, file-handling

below is my code, i need to write URL value in file with define path. but it output as URL and not replace with his define value, $string variable value cone from database.

```
<?php
define("URL","http://example.com/mail.php");
$string = 'Page here : {{URL}}'; // string come from database using query //
//$string = str_replace("{{","'.",$string);
//$string = str_replace("}}",".'",$string);

$f = fopen("d:\abc1.txt",'w');
$wr = fwrite($f,$string);
fclose($f);
?>
```

output in file was : Page here : {{URL}}

but i need something like this : Page here : {{http://example.com/mail.php}}

i also try using comment line to replace string and get out URL into string.

Comment: putting the url inside a var (with $ ) and the using concatenation (dot) no?

Comment: `$string = 'Page here : ' . URL';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I get it right, you have a dynamic string from DB, which somewhere contents this: '{{URL}}'. So just do simple replace like this:

```
define("URL","http://example.com/mail.php");
$string = str_replace('{{URL}}', '{{' . URL . '}}', $string);
```

This replaces URL text using URL value of that constant

Comment: thanks dear it's work but one more problem is there are many different define variable, and many different string which all not have same define variable in database so for each i need to write str_replace which is increase my code length, i have more then 200 define constant variable

Comment: You can use arrays to make it shorter, like $find = array('URL1', 'URL2', 'USER_ID',...); $repl = array(URL1, URL2, USER_ID, ...); $string = str_replace($find, $repl, $string); The disadvantage is, that you have to define your constants.

Answer (score 0):

Use your syntax like this :

`$string = "Page here : {{". URL ."}}"; // string come from database using query //`

As Mikec007 mentioned `str_replace()` will work for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
define("URL","http://example.com/mail.php");
$string = 'Page here : {{' . URL . '}}';
```

Comment: thanks dear but 'page here : {{ URL }}' string come from database so it have in one single quotation and hot have (.) concatenation

Comment: okay, then with a: str_replace('{{URL}}', '{{' . URL . '}}', $string)

Comment: what you have here also for problems? ... then I write here just nothing - adios